# How to hide the OK and Cancel buttons of antd Modal?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I wrote a `Signup` component, which is basically as follows:

```
const Login = (
  <Modal>
    <NormalLoginForm/ 
     ...
    </NormalLoginForm >
  </Modal>
)
```

The `NormalLoginForm` component is from the official website here https://ant.design/components/form/

I don't need the two Buttons `OK` and `Cancel` on the Modal, how to hide the two buttons ?

Also are there any good examples about how to integrate login and signup buttons with the navigation menu?

Comment: Edit: How do I display either of the buttons. Just "Ok" or "Cancel" button but not both?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

[Updated] I'm not sure what you exactly want to do. But according to the [doc](https://ant.design/components/modal/?locale=en-US#components-modal-demo-footer). You can customize your footer by using the attribute `footer` for **Modal**.

According to the updated document (Aug 31, 2021), we only need to use `footer={null}` and don't have to use `footer={null, null}` anymore.

Here is the sample: https://codepen.io/andretw/pen/RwbBYpb

```
<Modal
  visible={this.state.visible}
  title="Title"
  //onOk={this.handleOk}
  //onCancel={this.handleCancel}
  footer={null}
>Test For No TWO buttons on the footer.</Modal>
```

BTW, if you want to do `Login` and close the Modal by clicking one button, you need to invoke the handler function (handleOk) and set the visible option to **false** inside of it. (Nowadays, antd has great documents and you can check them to find more examples. I wrote and rewrote this example since there were few examples doing that at that time.)

```
// A handler/callback function 
handleLogin = () => {
  this.setState({ loading: true });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ loading: false, visible: false });
  }, 3000);
};

// Add a customized button to the footer
footer={[
  <Button key="submit" type="primary" loading={loading} onClick={this.handleLogin}>
  Login
  </Button>,
]}
```

Comment: How to hide modal-header's close button?

Comment: @MTM Maybe you can try "closeIcon" from the API doc?

Answer (score 44):

If you want to only hide a cancel button at the bottom and utilize `onCancel` for the X button at the top right corner then simply hide the cancel button like so: -

```
<Modal
    cancelButtonProps={{ style: { display: 'none' } }}
/>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for... Thanks

Comment: `okButtonProps={{ style: { display: 'none' } }}`  to remove ok button

Answer (score 15):

to remove

footer -> `footer={null}`

close Icon -> `closable={false}`

Ok button -> `okButtonProps={{ style: { display: 'none' } }}`

cancel button -> `cancelButtonProps={{ style: { display: 'none' } }}`

Comment: close Icon -> closable={false}
Worked for me

Answer (score 9):

You can do it by `footer={null}`

Comment: Thanks. That removes the footer all together along with border. Awesome!

Comment: Thank this is the neatest way . Just make sure anyone reading this to leave the onCancel props so you can still close the modal by pressing escape

Answer (score 5):

You can hide both `Ok` and `Cancel` button by:

```js
<Modal
  footer={null}
...
>
...
</Modal>
```

OR

```js
<Modal
 okButtonProps={{
          style: {
            display: "none",
          },
        }}
        cancelButtonProps={{
          style: {
            display: "none",
          },
        }}
...
>
...
</Modal>
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition, you can also hide close icon and customize as your need.

```
<Modal
  visible={this.state.visible}
  title="Title"
  closable={false}
  footer={null}>
  <div>
    Test For No two buttons on the footer.
    And No One in header.
  </div>
  <div>
    <Button type="ghost" onClick={this.handleClick}>Login</Button>
  </div>
</Modal>
```

You can also use others control as necessary.

```
static propTypes: {
        prefixCls: PropTypes.Requireable<string>;
        onOk: PropTypes.Requireable<(...args: any[]) => any>;
        onCancel: PropTypes.Requireable<(...args: any[]) => any>;
        okText: PropTypes.Requireable<PropTypes.ReactNodeLike>;
        cancelText: PropTypes.Requireable<PropTypes.ReactNodeLike>;
        centered: PropTypes.Requireable<boolean>;
        width: PropTypes.Requireable<React.ReactText>;
        confirmLoading: PropTypes.Requireable<boolean>;
        visible: PropTypes.Requireable<boolean>;
        footer: PropTypes.Requireable<PropTypes.ReactNodeLike>;
        title: PropTypes.Requireable<PropTypes.ReactNodeLike>;
        closable: PropTypes.Requireable<boolean>;
        closeIcon: PropTypes.Requireable<PropTypes.ReactNodeLike>;
    };
    handleCancel: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void;
    handleOk: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void;
    renderFooter: (locale: ModalLocale) => JSX.Element;
    renderModal: ({ getPopupContainer: getContextPopupContainer, getPrefixCls, }: ConfigConsumerProps) => JSX.Element;
    render(): JSX.Element;
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to hide the cancel button in Modal.confirm pass display as none to the cancelButtonProps. Please refer the below code.

```
 Modal.confirm({
    title: 'Confirm Title',
    content: 'ABC.....',
    okText:'OK',
    cancelButtonProps : { style: { display: 'none' } },  
    onOk: () => {
      // code to be implemented
    },
  });
```

In order to disable the cancel button pass disabled as true for the cancelButtonProps.

```
 Modal.confirm({
    title: 'Confirm Title',
    content: 'ABC.....',
    okText:'OK',
    cancelButtonProps : { disabled: true},  
    onOk: () => {
      // code to be implemented
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check [here](https://ant.design/components/modal/#components-modal-demo-footer)

```
<Model
  footer={null}
>
...
</Model>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you only want to remove buttons from modal then all you need is pass to Modal props

```
<Modal footer={null} {...rest}></Modal>
```

if you also want to disable close posibility then you need to pass also

```
<Modal closable={false} footer={null} {...rest}></Modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

pass footer= {null} in the Modal props

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the footer props.

```
    <Modal 
      footer={[]}
    >
    <ShoutOutModal />
  </Modal>
```

and if you want to return just the cancel button you can do

```
      <Modal 
    
    footer={[<Button>Cancel</Button>]}
  >
    <ShoutOutModal />
  </Modal>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just want to disable the OK button, when the state is loading.

```html
<Modal
  okButtonProps={{
    style: {
      cursor: loading ? 'not-allowed' : 'default',
    },
  }}
></Modal>
```